# COM : retrieve good CLSID

Tags: c++, com, clsid

I have a little problem with the CLSID.

I have a (hooked) function which has in param a REFCLSID.
So I want to print this param.

I did:

```
LPOLESTR pOleStr;
StringFromCLSID(rclsid,&pOleStr); //rclsid is a REFCLSID type.
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("C:\\output.txt",ios::app);
myfile << pOleStr << std::endl;
myfile.close();
```

But in "output.txt", I just have a 8 character string,
but I should have a string like : 111111-2222-3333-4444-000000000000.

So if anyone has an idea...

Thanks.

Comment: What 8-character string do you get?

Comment: The pointer value.  Just cast to (const wchar_t*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, I think that LPOLESTR is widechar, you'd have to convert it to ASCII using

```
CHAR  szCLSID[60];
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pOleStr, -1, szCLSID, 60, NULL, NULL);
```

Also don't forget to  `CoTaskMemFree(pOleStr)` afterwards :)